# Pandas number of unique/distinct characters in a string

Tags: python, pandas

How do we calculate the number of unique characters in a string in pandas dataframe? I have data in column like this:

| Number | phone (type string) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100012 |
| 2 | 121111 |
| 3 | 121127 |
| 4 | 465222 |

I want to add another column which mentions the length of unique characters in each string.

Expected output:

| Number | phone (type string) | unique_characters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100012 | 3 |
| 2 | 121111 | 2 |
| 3 | 121127 | 3 |
| 4 | 465222 | 4 |

So far, I have tried:

```
df['unique_characters'] = len(set(df['phone']))
```

However, the above code gives me this result:

| Number | phone (type string) | unique_characters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100012 | 159378 |
| 2 | 121111 | 159378 |
| 3 | 121127 | 159378 |
| 4 | 465222 | 159378 |

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No lambda:

```py
>>> df['phone'].apply(set)
0       {0, 1, 2}
1          {1, 2}
2       {7, 1, 2}
3    {5, 6, 4, 2}
Name: phone, dtype: object
```

and

```py
>>> df['phone'].apply(set).apply(len)
0    3
1    2
2    3
3    4
Name: phone, dtype: int64
```

Note: as correctly noted by @mozway, the double-apply is slower than a single apply with lambda, or than, even better, a dedicated function. But if you are looking to store *both* the set of unique digits and their length, then you would do one `.apply(set)` for the former and `.apply(len)` on it for the latter.

**Timing**

```py
n = 1_000_000
df = pd.DataFrame({'phone': np.random.randint(1e4, 1e9, size=n).astype(int).astype(str)})

%timeit df['phone'].apply(set).apply(len)
# 1.17 s ± 1.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df['phone'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))
# 738 ms ± 4.87 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

def nu(x):
    return len(set(x))

%timeit df['phone'].apply(nu)
# 698 ms ± 1.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: the OP mentioned the column 'phone' is already type str

Comment: A double apply is not efficient though. Better use a lambda/function to combine set and len in one operation.

Comment: @mozway, yes indeed, somehow I had in mind the goal of getting both (sets of unique digits, and their length).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `len` + `np.unique`:

```
df['unique_characters'] = df['phone'].apply(lambda x: len(np.unique([*x])))
```

Output:

```
   Number   phone  unique_characters
0       1  100012                  3
1       2  121111                  2
2       3  121127                  3
3       4  465222                  4
```